# Flutter, run async function on stream.listen

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, stream

I have a stream of data that gets me messages, and on each message, I want to execute an HTTP request, i.e. an async function. How can I do that?

Minimum reproducible example:

```
Future<int> myFuture(int n) async {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));  // Mock future
  print("Future finished for: $n");
  return n;
}

Stream<int> countStream(int to) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() async {
  var stream = countStream(10);
  stream.listen((n) { await myFuture(n); });
  // or simply: stream.listen(myFuture);
}
```

Essentially I can't await `myFuture`.

Thank you

Comment: `await` can be used only within a function marked `async`: `stream.listen((n) async { await myFuture(n); });` But note that nothing will be able to wait for your listener callback to complete, and unless your callback does other work after `await myFuture(n);`, the `await` won't accomplish anything.

Comment: `countStream(10).asyncMap(myFuture)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to reiterate from pskink- yes this would be the best way to send and receive every data from the future:

```
void main() async {
  var stream = countStream(10).asyncMap((n) => myFuture(n));
  stream.listen((n) {
    print('received $n from stream');
  });
}
```

returns in this example:

```
Future finished for: 1
received 1 from stream
Future finished for: 2
received 2 from stream
Future finished for: 3
received 3 from stream
Future finished for: 4
received 4 from stream
Future finished for: 5
received 5 from stream
Future finished for: 6
received 6 from stream
Future finished for: 7
received 7 from stream
Future finished for: 8
received 8 from stream
Future finished for: 9
received 9 from stream
Future finished for: 10
received 10 from stream
```

But the classic construction works as well and does the same so the main would look like this:

```
void main() async {
  var stream = countStream(10);
  stream.listen((n) {
    myFuture(n);
    print('received $n from stream');
  });
}
```

And this returns the same thing as previous solution. Choosing this one or previous still gives you reliable one-by-one returns from your future, that are ready to use later when stream receives data.

Edit: to answer your question from comment- you have full certainty that the future will complete. Only thing that could fail in this situation is the network call so you'd have to do some smart try/catch or switch statements for different failures so that they still return something or make the observable value nullable (witk the `?` mark).

Even if we assume that some calls take longer than others you still receive data chronologically. Let's test it like this:

```
Future<int> myFuture(int n) async {
  var seconds = Random().nextInt(25);
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds));  // Mock future
  print("Future finished for: $n, completion time: $seconds");
  return n;
}
```

The return look like so:

```
Future finished for: 1, completion time: 24
received 1 from stream
Future finished for: 2, completion time: 23
received 2 from stream
Future finished for: 3, completion time: 18
received 3 from stream
Future finished for: 4, completion time: 6
received 4 from stream
Future finished for: 5, completion time: 11
received 5 from stream
Future finished for: 6, completion time: 2
received 6 from stream
Future finished for: 7, completion time: 22
received 7 from stream
Future finished for: 8, completion time: 15
received 8 from stream
Future finished for: 9, completion time: 5
received 9 from stream
Future finished for: 10, completion time: 2
received 10 from stream
```

You can test it with a real example like so:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<dynamic> myFuture(int n) async {
    final response = await http.Client().get(
      Uri.https(
        'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        '/posts/$n',
      ),
    );

    return response.body;
}

Stream<int> countStream(int to) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() async {
  var stream = countStream(10).asyncMap((n) => myFuture(n));
  stream.listen((n) {
    print('received $n from stream');
  });
}
```

In the log see how post ID is according to the data from stream that was sent to the Future and it returned correctly in chronological order- first data in, first data out.

You should be able to use `asyncMap` no matter what library you're using. In this last example I'm passing a `dynamic` datatype meaning you're still getting any object as precisely THE object you declare in a single object form that you can use anywhere as you so please.

Comment: In the second solution, I am guaranteed that the future will complete even if I dont await it? How does that work? Could you explain with more detail please? I am new to async programming. Regarding the first solution, I am not sure I can define asyncMap because I am using a library to receive messages and think I dont have access to that function. I ll look into it. What would be the difference between both approaches?

Comment: @Alexis I hope the edits make it more clear :)